# Shell script searching for regular files

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need a shell script to look for regular files in a directory given as argument and count them in order to display their number.

Answer (score 2):

`find /some/path -name "aaa.*" | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/ksh

cd $1
list=`ls -l | grep -v '^d' | wc -l`
echo $list
```